# Can't change cursor while dragging over an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the cursor to `copy` while dragging an element over the specified droppable. *I use this to upload files from the local file system via drag and drop into the browser window.* I can change the appearance of the element but the cursor won't change. Here's the code I'm using:

#### HTML

```
<div class="droppable"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.droppable {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.droppable.active {
    background: green;
    cursor: copy;
}
```

#### JS

```
droppable = $('.droppable');

droppable.on('dragover dragenter', function(event) {
    droppable.addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

droppable.on('dragleave', function(event) {
    droppable.removeClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can try it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/27px4u5h/

The demo contains also a second (orange) element that shows how the cursor should look like.

Why is this not working?

Comment: can you post the draggable code?

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri Ah sorry, I want to drop files from the local file system. That's all the code I'm using. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: you should use an id for your draggable

Comment: @RachelGallen Can you provide some information why I should use an id? What's wrong with a class? I also may have multiple of those elements. :)

Comment: @lampshade actually it's ok it's just you were calling another class .active first but if you're just going to use :active then its ok to use a class not an id, especially if you have multiple instances

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/27px4u5h/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested you code in Chrome and FF. And it seems that chrome is successfully running your code BUT FF is not running your code it might be due to some restriction or required support resources, i'm not sure about that one.

Hope it might give you some help.

Comment: One more trick you can try, put some text in div like <div class="droppable">ABC</div> AND select ABC and drag this then you see dragging is working FF